# Tumblr Theme - How to make the reblog caption seperate from the actual caption?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

Ok, im making a tumblr blog and having a bit of trouble.

When I reblog a photoset that has a caption, I then add my own caption aswell.

When I look at it on my page my caption is just below the person I reblogged it from, making it look like they wrote it not me.

I would like to be able to edit it and add my tumblr name above my caption only. I am not sure how to do this as both captions are in tumblrs '{caption}' tag.

example:
Their caption
My caption

... all tumblr does is put my caption on a different line

extra info about my skills:

- I started my tumblr theme from scratch
- I know html and css well
- I know a bit of jquery

**Any help is appreciated.**

GOT IT TO WORK!!

FIX -

for the basic look add this to css...

```
blockquote {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 2px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: Tumblr {Caption} variable separates comments with blockquotes. Try adding a left border to them and it should make it more legible.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I haven't been able to get it to work yet. I am unsure how you would write it in CSS.

In HTML would i just have it as the '{caption}' tag where I want it.

But when referring to it in CSS, what would I used?

blockquotes {
  border-left: 1px solid black
}

like that? but I havent written 'blockqoutes' in my html.

thanks

Comment: nvm, i got it to work. just had to add 'display: block;'

thanks!!!